# File permision and compare char with int in C

Tags: c, file-permissions

I have in octal2 the File permission in octal given as a parameter. ex:777
Statchmod should have the  File permission from a file "file_name" given as parameter.

I have a file with 777 permission but Stachmod gets 448 and I don't know why.
Also I don't know how to compare octal2 with Stachmod in the If Statement

```
char octal2[7];

    read(fd2[0], octal2, 7);

        // verify the octal permission of the file and give the result on the answear

        struct stat buf;  
    stat(file_name, &buf);
    int statchmod = buf.st_mode & (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
    printf("The statchmod is %d\n", statchmod);

    if (statchmod ==  octal2[0])
     {
        char answear[]="Totul e OK!"; //OK
        printf("The answear is %s\n", answear);
     }
    else
     {

        chmod(file_name, S_IRWXU);

        char answear[]="Drepturile au fost modificate"; //not OK

        printf("The answear is %s\n", answear);
     }
```

Comment: `448` in decimal is `700` in octal. This is the mode you are setting and not `777`. If you want to display in octal, use `%o` format specifier.

Comment: Ok,thanks! But how can I compare statchmod to octal2?

Comment: You can convert the string `octal2` to a `long` value using function `strtol`. Specify base 8. see https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol.